# SQL SERVER SSAS DSCV

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas

I was maintaining a SSAS project. and I saw DSV dimensions and facts are not linked could anyone please comment if this could deteriorate performance,

Thanks & Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this affects performance at all.  My understanding is that it is a nice to have.  If you have all of your facts and dimension tables/views linked in the DSV, it automatically populates the dimension usage when you add new dimensions/facts. The dimension usage tab is where your measure groups are actually related to dimensions.  I think the relationships in your DSV are just there to help with design to create a clear picture for you.